# How do you add a dimension to the datapoints without using Lambda layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to classify the `fashion_mnist`dataset using the `Conv2D` layer and as I know it can be easily done using the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

fashion_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, axis=-1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(28,28),batch_size=32),      
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(4,kernel_size=3),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x=train_images, y=train_labels, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels), epochs=10)
```

However, I am required to **not use Lambda layer**. so, the above solution is not correct.

So, I am wondering, how can i classify the `mnist_fashion` dataset without using Lambda layer ?

Update:
When i add the a dimention using the below code:

```
train_images = train_images / 255.0
train_images = tf.expand_dims(train_images,axis=0)

test_images = test_images / 255.0
test_images = tf.expand_dims(test_images,axis=0)
```

and run it against the same model, i get the following error:

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 1
  y sizes: 60000
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

Comment: @AloneTogether Do you have any idea?

Comment: Ok, removed comment and added answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple options:
Using `expand_dims` directly on `train_images` and changing the input shape or using a `Reshape` layer instead of a `Lambda` layer or removing the layer completely and changing the input_shape `tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(28,28, 1),batch_size=32)`. Depends what you want. Here is the `expand_dims` option across `axis=-1`:

```
train_images = train_images / 255.0
train_images = tf.expand_dims(train_images, axis=-1)

test_images = test_images / 255.0
test_images = tf.expand_dims(test_images, axis=-1)
```

And change the `Input` layer to `tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1)`

**Q1** Answer: Because `Conv2D` layers require a 3D input (excluding the batch size) so something like: `(rows, cols, channels)`. Your data had the shape `(samples, 28, 28)`. If your channels came before rows and cols, you could use `expand_dims` on the `axis=1` resulting in `(samples, 1, 28, 28)` instead of `(samples, 28, 28, 1)` when using `axis=-1`. If the former is the case, you would have to set the `data_format` parameter in the `Conv2D` layer to `channels_first`. Using `axis=0` results in the shape `(1 samples, 28,  28)`, which is incorrect, because the first dimension should be reserved as the batch dimension.

**Q2** Answer: I used `shape=(28, 28, 1)` because the fashion mnist images are grayscale images. That is, they have one channel (which we have explicitly defined). RGB images, on the other hand, have 3 channels: Red channel, Green channel and Blue channel.

Comment: Thanks. it works now, but i have 2 questions. 1. Why do you add the new dimention to the last axis ? Usually we have `(Batch_size,image_row,image_columns,color_code)`, so i believe we should add the an extra dimention to the first part ? 

my second question is, why did you use `shape=(28, 28, 1)` instead of `shape=(28, 28, 3)` . As you know value of each pixel is between 0 and 255 and the images are colorful.

Comment: See updated answer @Jeff

Comment: About your answer to Q2: I know that the `fashion_mnist` is a grayscale dataset, however if try to plot one of the images using the following code, then you see it is colorful image:

`fashion_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

#------------------------------ Visualize the sample entry
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(train_images[0])
plt.show()`

Comment: `matplotlib` applies pseudocolor to these images by default. According to the docs:  "Pseudocolor can be a useful tool for enhancing contrast and visualizing your data more easily"

Comment: ok. So, the best way to understand the color channel of the dataset is to refer to the documentation of the dataset ? Right ?

Comment: Just check the shape of the images in the dataset. RGB images will have the 3 channels that you will see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244324/discussion-between-jeff-and-alonetogether).